# How to use Row-Level Security to weed out deleted records

Tags: sql-server-2017, row-level-security

We're looking for help with an issue that I hope can be solved with row-level security.  We have 160 tables feed by a data lake that are in turn used by another application. There is a field in all tables called *IsDeleted* that is 0 if the record is good and 1 if deleted. What we need is for any user except the system application called *ETLapp*, they should only see records where *IsDeleted*=0.

Using the Microsoft examples,
CREATE users

```
CREATE USER mylogin WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER yourlogin WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER ETLapp WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
```

Then create table

```
CREATE SCHEMA SALES
GO
CREATE TABLE SALES.Orders
(OrderID int,
SalesRep nvarchar(50),
Product nvarchar(50),
Quantity smallint,
IsDeleted bit
);
```

Populate the Table

```
INSERT INTO SALES.Orders VALUES (1, 'Fred', 'Valve', 5, 0);
INSERT INTO SALES.Orders VALUES (2, 'Daphne', 'Wheel', 2, 0);
INSERT INTO SALES.Orders VALUES (3, 'Scooby', 'Pizza', 1, 1);
SELECT * from SALES.Orders;
```

Grant Access

```
GRANT SELECT ON Sales.Orders TO mylogin;
GRANT SELECT ON Sales.Orders to yourlogin;
GRANT SELECT ON Sales.Orders to ETLapp;
```

Here's the part I can't make work right.

```
CREATE FUNCTION rls.SalesPredicate(@UserName as sysname)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN SELECT 1 AS SalesPredicate_result
WHERE IsDeleted =0 OR UserName = 'ETLapp';
GO
```

It executes okay, but when I create the security policy, it won't accept username because username is not in the table, and if I pass it IsDeleted then we get all the rows.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY SalesFilter 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE rls.SalesPredicate(UserName)
ON Sales.Orders
WITH (STATE=ON);
GO
```

user ETLapp should see all 3 records, but anyone else should only see the two where IsDeleted=0.

Comment: And you cannot solve that on application level? So that the application identifies the user and accordingly adds a `WHERE IsDeleted = 0` where needed?

Comment: Here a bit an exotic idea: You could create a second database that has only views with the same names as the tables in the main database (schema name + table name) and performs a filtered select on the original table in the main database. And for the main database only a few people have access and for the filtered one the main portion of users.

Comment: No, I can't. Our company is upgrading from a single-tenant version of our CRM/Financial to multi-tenant, and part of that change is a datalake structure. I can't alter the tables or such, all I can do is try to mitigate the deleted=0 with RLS, or triggered Deletes on the 1s (and hope not to lock tables) or other similar tasks to mitigate the issue.